# 'No valid code signing identity found' error

Tags: ios, certificate, distribution, profile, xcode4.3

I know this is flogging a very dead horse, trust me I've gone through every question on here and tried everything that's been advised.  No beans.  I'm missing something my brain is not capable of seeing.

So, my app is ready for release version 1 (thanks for all the help btw) and I'm going through the pain of uploading it for Apple to reject ;)  I started the app on another machine, so I exported my private key and imported it to my new system.  I then created a distribution profile and installed that, only to get the message of hate from Xcode.  After 8 hours of shouting I decided to revoke my certificate, delete all my profiles and go to bed.  This morning I created a new developer certificate on my new system, created a new provision profile, and installed everything.  I can run my app on my device, all good (in fact, better than good, some warnings vanished).

But, here it comes, I still get the 'no valid code signing' error when I create a distribution profile.

I've watched several Youtube vids, I do nothing wrong according to them.  I read Apple's documentation (which let's be honest is a mess) and I did everything it told me, but it's so vague I probably missed something.  And I read through everything I found here, to no avail.

Is there, somewhere, anywhere (please) a step by step walk through which is up to date?  Every one I found was Xcode 3 or the screen caps from the dev centre don't match.

I'm going to be heading to the pub if anyone in London wants to join me and shout at Apple for making this such a mess.

Screen caps if it helps?

[image: Keychain Access is happy]

[image: XCode is grumpy]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that [this Ray tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/8003/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-1) is very well made.

Comment: By the way, you do realize that your distribution certificate is a *different* certificate than your development one...right?

Comment: yes, it's now working.  My distributor cert needed to be revoked and re-created.  The dates matched, but the certs didn't.  Anyway, I was writing my answer as you were writ in this comment :)

Comment: I'm giving the answer rep to borrrden as his comments pointed me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I'm leaving this here for other people who stumble across this nightmare and, like me, are a bit dumb/tired/lack caffeine.

After revoking and re-creating my developer certificate, I had not revoked and re-created my distributor certificate.  I thought I had, the dates matched (today) but in fact I hadn't.  I re-created that, and all was good.  This may have been a bug, or it may have been me, or a bit of both.  But re-creating the distributor cert AFTER re-creating the developer cert fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error after upgrading to iOS8 / xcode6, you will need to manually sign in with your appleID to the member center and downloaded the certificates directly. Then add them to your keychain and you are off to the races again.